# Не могу добавить title через functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Вот код который по сценарию должен добавить title в head, но он почему-то не работает.

```
  `function freelancer_theme_support(){
      add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );}

  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'freelancer_theme_support' );`
```

Comment: Как title выводите?

Comment: Тег title из head я вообще удалил, по идее он же должен автоматически добавляться благодаря выше написанной функции.

Answer (score 0):

```
function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
}
```